# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am working for the first time on angular and I have to fix a bug. A website which was working fine suddenly causing few errors and the results are not loading. I have these errors in console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at a.$$ChildScope.$$ChildScope.$scope.numberOfPages (custom.js:27)
at angular.js:12332
at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:12735)
at l.$digest (angular.js:14217)
at l.$apply (angular.js:14488)
at l (angular.js:9646)
at O (angular.js:9836)
at XMLHttpRequest.w.onload (angular.js:9777)
```

This is how I am loading these files in my header.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/xeditable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/apps/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I think these are lines in custom.js file which are causing this error.

```
$scope.numberOfPages = function() {

  if ($scope.filtered) {
    return Math.ceil($scope.filtered.length / $scope.pageSize);
  } else if ($scope.datatable.data) {
    return Math.ceil($scope.datatable.data.data.length / $scope.pageSize);
  }

};
```

Again it was working previously and now suddenly results are not loading and I have errors in console. Any suggestion regarding this will help a lot as I am working on angular project for the first time.

Comment: Where's the code that throws the error?

Comment: do you have a file custom.js ? `$$ChildScope.$$ChildScope.$scope.numberOfPages` seems weird, is it written raw in code ?

Comment: Yes I have custom.js file and I think within this file above mention lines are causing this error but still I am not sure.

Comment: Don't dump unformatted code blobs into comments...update the question with formatted code that we can read

Comment: Problem looks like it is likely `$scope.datatable.data.data.length` so inspect what `$scope.datatable.data.data` returns ... or `$scope.filtered.length` could be it. The `data.data` looks suspicious

Comment: @charlietfl how I can test output for these

Comment: Use `console.log(variable)` and open browser dev tools console

Comment: With this it started to display this error twice. On the other hand for the return I just added a custom digit for both if and else conditions and after this there was no error but still the results are not loading for me. Thank you for your help and I am not sure whether I will be able to fix this and you will be able to understand this issue or not.

Comment: What is `$scope.datatable.data.data`...is it undefined? You need to find where `length` is being evaluated on `undefined` where it is expected to be an array instead